# How to see posts using functions based view in django?

Tags: python, django, forms, backend

In my current django project I had to make a function to render the home page so that I could make a form in it, which form is in the base.html so that can be rendered in every page post of the website, the current code is this:

```py
def contactView(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(subject, 
                          message, 
                          email, 
                          ['example@gmail.com'],
                          fail_silently=False)
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('home')
    return render(request, "index.html", {'form': form})
```

which *works*, but the view for every post is a class-based-view that display the form perfectly:

```
class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    extra_context = {'form': ContactForm()}
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'
```

The only problem is that the form in the homepage works because there is the code, the same code that I do not know how to call into a class (otherwise I would have used a class even for the home)

for more detail the urls.py is:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [ 
    path('', views.contactView, name = 'home'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name = 'post_detail'),
]
```

Basically, in the post form there is the slug that get added to the path in the new rendered page, if I click on `fourth post` i get redirected to HTTP://127.0.0.1/fourth-post.

My problem Is that the form in every post doesn't work but only in the homepage and this because there is no code, obviously. So I can do two different things:

- remake the post class to make it basically a copy of the home function
- make a method with the same code in it that makes the code works

I would like to do the second, but being a newbie in django I do not know how to do it, any help or insight would be great

Comment: Do you want to display your contact form on post detail page or home page?

Comment: Both, hence the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this in your **contactView** using function based view

```
def contactView(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        post = Post.objects.all()
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(subject, 
                          message, 
                          email, 
                          ['example@gmail.com'],
                          fail_silently=False)
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('home')
    return render(request, "index.html", {'form': form,'post':post})
```

and for post detail you can do something like this

```
def post_detail(request,slug):
    post = Post.objects.filter(slug=slug)
    form = ContactForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(subject, 
                message, 
                email, 
                ['example@gmail.com'],
                fail_silently=False)
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('home')
    return render(request, "post_detail.html", {'form': form,'post':post})
```

Comment: thanks, the only thing is that `post = Post.objects.filter(slug=slug)` should be `post = Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()` to get the actual post object, other than that it seem to work and gives no problem. I can't really test it because I have no service to send emails for now and the email doesn't appear in the console, if I'll have any problems I'll edit the problem, for now you have been more than great 

Comment: I have tried to send an email with a service, and although it got an error because I set bad the info in setting.py you code actually *sended* the email, thanks